# Table column width in multirow

Tags: tables, tabularx

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]

\begin{tabular}{|lL{2cm}cc|}

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Text} & \multirow{2}{*}{Long text text} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text} \\
& & text & text\\\hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

How to fix the columnwidth of the `Long text text`?

Comment: Since it is a column with fixed width, use  `\multirow{2}{=}{Long text text}`.

Comment: Perfectly works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.